# Application.Current.MainWindow and splash screen

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I'm using custom splash screen for my application, which is actually another window. I'm creating it in App constructor (to be exact, in one of setup methods called from there) and destroying it in `OnStartup` event (right after application window is created).

But it seems, that application gets splash screen as main window (since it is called before actual app window is created), and this causes numerous problems. So, how can I make my app to ignore splash screen window (in `Application.Current.MainWindow` context)?

Note, that I'm creating app window programmaticaly, so I can't simply specify it in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the application's `MainWindow` to be any `Window` using the static `MainWindow` property of `Application`:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = MyWindow;
```

Comment: That's what I've actually did, check my own question

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms600305(v=vs.110).aspx), the first Window instantiated in the AppDomain is placed in MainWindow. So, it seems I need to assign it manually.